# Connection issues on Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server, networking

So my friend just got Minecraft and she can play on single player mode but once she joins a server it times her out after 2 min. She has uninstalled it, cleared her cache, she also did a dns flush. She has reset her router, turned off windows defender, turned off firewall and her virus protection. We don’t know what the issue is and every video we found doesn’t seem to help anything. Can you guys please help?

Comment: It is Java. She has the most recent update from the official website

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because of either of these things:

- Your internet is slow
- The server has lots of players

Try joining a less frequent server and see if it solves the problem.

If that's not the case however, the only option you have left is to contact your ISP and change your internet plan.